# How to save images in mysql database using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I know that you can do .to_sql to stack Python dataframes in the mysql database. So how can images be stacked in a mysql database? (using sqlalchemy)

Comment: I would look into `BINARY` column type. https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.BINARY